# Wix UIMinimal dialogue not showing image

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix

I did the following setup for custom banner / dialog image and license text:

```html
    <UI>
      <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog"
        Control="Finish" 
        Event="DoAction" 
        Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1</Publish>
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
    </UI>
    
    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="LicenseAgreement.rtf" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="My banner.png" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="My dialog.png" />
```

I see strange behaviours happening for both Windows 7 and Windows 10 installers:

### Windows 10

Banner and dialog display OK (correct image is a background image with left side black and right side white), but license agreement has a weird behaviour. As shown in first picture, License agreement is just a white space, but if you try to select over it, the text shows up (second picture)

[image]

[image]

If you scroll all over it and deselect it will show all the license agreement fine but only after doing this, and not when initially starting the installer. Every single time you start the installer it will show a white screen and you'll have to do the selection or scrolling to reveal the text.

### Windows 7

Banners don't show at all, and License agreement won't show at all!

[image]

However, after selecting text on licence agreement at least licence agreement will show, but it's still unexpected (it should show by default and not after you select / scroll)

[image]

[image]

Is there anything wrong with the images / text ? I just created a plain rtf file with the license agreement. And the images are pngs which I assume Wix converts / resizes to the correct format

### Update:

License issue was fixed by saving rtf using Word Pad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like, there is a known issue with rich text control and your license. According WiX [documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html), one of the following workarounds will fix it in most cases:

- Open your RTF file in WordPad and save it from there in order to
  remove the complex RTF content from the file. After saving it,
  rebuild your MSI.
- Use a dialog set other than the `WixUI_Minimal` set. This problem
  typically only occurs when the license agreement screen is the
  first one displayed during setup, which only happens with the
  `WixUI_Minimal` dialog set.

As for the images, MSI bitmap control supports only BMP and JPEG files, PNG is supported starting from Windows 8, according to [MSI bitmap control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/bitmap-control)

Comment: Thanks, this solves half of the problem, the image in dialog issue is still broken :(

Comment: @gbdavid Does it work with default images? Try to use bmp instead of png and check the exact sizes of the images

Comment: default images are ok, and the png image is fine in Windows 10... it only breaks in window 7 :(

Comment: @gbdavid Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392654/is-it-possible-to-use-png-images-for-wix-bitmaps) and this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/bitmap-control) Seems like, PNG is supported starting from Windows 8. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you Pavel, yes converting to BMP solves the problem for Windows 7.

Comment: FWIW, I have an open source project called IsWiX that has project templates that addresses all of these concerns out of the box.  https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials  If you poke around the sample source projects you can see how the .wixproj, .wxs  and resources directory all come together to guide a new project into using the right format files.  There's even a comment in the EULA.rtf that talks about how old the MSI RTF control is.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter It's awesome, will have a look